# how can we sort files according to their size using cmd batch files and print a wait timer till the loop is running?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, command-line, wmic

How can we sorting the files with size in the decreasing order.
What should i add ?

```
for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do ( if exist %%d: ( echo Another process is running !! Please wait !!! && dir %%d:\ /s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%))
```

And if I want to print a timer till the time loop is running, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort the files by size in decreasing order, you can add the `"/o:-s` option to the "dir" command.

```
for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d: (
    echo Listing files in %%d:
    dir %%d:\ /s /o:-s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%
  )
)
```

To print a message while the loop is running, you can use the "echo" command as you suggested.

```
@echo off
set Systeminfo_TXT=output.txt

echo Starting file listing...
for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d: (
    echo Listing files in %%d...
    dir %%d:\ /s /o:-s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%
  )
)

echo File listing complete.
```

Comment: a timer while the loop is running, you can use the "timeout" command in combination with a loop counter.

Comment: any time... let me know if you need any other help. Curious to self check my skills too. A challenge every day will keep the techies sharp and smart. haha.

Comment: ahaha indeed very true